# Microsoft.Build.Framework specify tools version

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a target project that uses c# 6.0 I need to programatically build it.

I have the code below:

```
        var pc = new ProjectCollection();
        pc.DefaultToolsVersion = "14.0" //set tools version
        var globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Configuration", "Release"},
            {"Platform", "Any CPU"},
            {"OutputPath", Utils.GetGaugeBinDir()}
        };

        var buildRequestData = new BuildRequestData(solutionFullPath, globalProperty, "14.0", new[] {"Build"}, null); //Set tools version here as well

        var errorCodeAggregator = new ErrorCodeAggregator();
        var buildParameters = new BuildParameters(pc) {Loggers = new ILogger[] {consoleLogger, errorCodeAggregator}};

        var buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequestData);
```

No matter where I set the tools version (of the two options above), it does not build C# 6.0.

On command line, I can do this:

```
msbuild foo.csproj /tv:14.0 /t:rebuild
```

I invoke this from MSBuild 12.0 bin directory, and it works. If I drop the `/tv:14.0` flag, it fails as expected.

So, question is, what is the programatic way of specifying `/tv` flag to `BuildManager` ?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. Did you figure out a solution? Currently the log file from my build suggests it is unable to build C# 6.0 syntax. I'm setting both the DefaultToolsVersion of the ProjectCollection instance and the BuildRequestData paramter as 14.0. Clearly that's wrong (or insufficient).

Comment: @AlexanderHøst - I'm afraid not. I have two ways forward to fix this: (1) upgrade my code to use MSBuild 14.0 or (2) invoke msbuild process and pass the relevant parameters. I don't like either very much, so am leaving it as it is for now :(

Answer (score 1):

```
var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(_solutionPath, globalProperties, null, new[] {"Build"},
```

When creating your BuildRequestData, pass null for the toolsVersion.

Then make sure the Microsoft.Build*.dll's referenced by your project are the correct version.
By default, VS will add the ones from inside it's own install directory. The updated ones should exist at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin"

Comment: The context is that I want to be able to invoke the build against one of many msbuild version. i.e. if I know my target solution is authored using c# 6.0, I would use msbuild 14.0, else I would like to use msbuild 12.0. Having to include msbuild 14.0 as a dependency would require me to upgrade to .net 4.6.2 I guess? I would rather not impose that on all my users yet.